# Is a .NET image completely black?

Tags: c#, .net, image

Given a .NET Image object, how do I check if it represents a picture that's completely black? (C#)

10x!

Comment: Go for it Mitch, I am here for moral support anyways!

Comment: @user181218: my sense of humor. nvm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your image to a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwdz9wf7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and use its `GetPixel()`-Method to check the color of the pixel at position x, y. If all pixels are black, the image is black.

Comment: Great. The bitmap.getpixel() was exactly what i was missing. from there testing if it's black is indeed trivial.